# python multiprocessing read write lock

Tags: python, multiprocessing, locking, readwritelock

I have multiprocessing python code using multiprocessing.Lock. I would like to change it to have read-write lock instead of simple lock. I was looking for an implementation of it but the only multiple readers / single writer locks I have found in python are based on threading not multiprocessing interface.

My question is does anyone knows if there is a way to use read-write lock in python  multiprocessing ?

Comment: Take a look at [multiprocessing-utils](https://pypi.org/project/multiprocessing-utils/)

Comment: I do not quite understand why someone can under vote this question. It is a total valid one. There is practically nothing about this topic on internet.... And I think this is essential when you want to improve a little bit the python weak performance

Answer (score 0):

Multiprocessing-utils dones't work for me.

There is some third_part read_write_lock which is writed for multiThreading case, u have to make a bit change before it can be used in multiprocessing case.

Here is the code:https://github.com/unhappydog/multiprocessing_read_write_lock/blob/master/rwlock/rwlock.py